# syncsort(dmxexpress) produces weird output

Tags: linux, sorting, syncsort-dmx-h

I'm trying to sort:

1

4

11

10

2

3

using syncsort.
The result looks like:

1

10

11

2

3

4

How to fix this.

I used the command:

syncsort /workspace /mytmp/   /infile /work/in_test  /fields fld1 1 char 4 /keys fld1 ascending /outfile /work/out_test overwrite /noprompt /end

Comment: It looks like the sort is treating the data as a string, you want it to sort as a number.

Comment: You are not using the SyncSORT of the tag you chose, so I've updated that.Yes, the `char` is the problem. You have a left-justified number. I don't know enough about your non-Mainframe SyncSORT to make a good suggestion as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to key declaration. You should give length 2 as a key. It will get you your desired output.

Currently it is only sorting 1st position so you are getting this wired output.

SORT FIELDS=(1,2,CH,A)